# PHP: Custom error handler for PDO?

Tags: php, exception, error-handling, pdo

I am attempting to try to do something useful with PDO exceptions other than display them, but I cannot find for the life of me how to use an error handler (set_error_handler) or anything custom to deal with PDOs exceptions.

Now I am using `try`..`catch` blocks of course the catch the exception, do I implement a custom error handler in the `catch` part, or can I skip the try->catch block completely as the exception handler would handle it for me (by calling `or throw new exception (...)` on the statement?

I guess what I am asking is an example to catch PDO exceptions and log them more or less (any simple code correct or not I can use, I'm not TOO dumb).

Comment: Heh.. when googling `set_error_handler pdo` this comes up first page.. Odd it's not talked about much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You'll have to use a try..catch block around each PDO query. Add your log function in the catch part. There is no generic handler for exceptions in PHP.

```
try {  
   pdo::error();  
}  
catch (Exception $e) {  
   syslog($e);  
}
```

If you want to avoid the try..catch blocks you can however configure PDO to only show errors instead of throwing exceptions. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

```
 $pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );
```

Comment: Awesome, I can just use error handler then (I found a really nice function to log errors to disk).

Comment: Your default set_error_handler() will see all PDO warnings, just like any other errors.

Comment: Accepted gladly, I decided to just leave it to PHP's own error handling with this (display errors off, log_errors on for ease of implementation). Thank you.